# fo:block-container and FOP compliance

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I would like to use `fo:block-container` in my XSLT sheets and resulting XSL-FO. For instance, to change the orientation of a table:

```
<fo:block-container 
 reference-orientation="90"
 break-before="page"
 break-after="page">
  <fo:table>
  <!--Table content-->
  </fo:table>
</fo:block-container>
```

Then, I apply FOP and generate a PDF from the XSL-FO.

The Apache FOP compliance page (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html) says that FOP is only **partially compliant** in the case of `fo:block-container`. Does anyone know which properties are not supported or how this is going to affect the resulting PDF?

Comment: Is there something that you are trying to do with block-container that doesn't work?

Comment: Thing is, I got cryptic error code from FOP and thought it could be due to the partial compliance. Also, I can't upload code because it's confidential. In the meantime, I solved this without containers.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know about fop compliance, but some time ago I used fop-extensions for rotating a container:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions" version="2.0">
 <fo:block-container  position="absolute" fox:transform="rotate(90)">
    ...
 </fo:block-container>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

find more information on fop extensions in the link below.

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/extensions.html